# Definite integral with no closed form antiderivative

Tags: calculus, analysis

Now from wikipedia I know that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt\pi.$$  Also on wikipedia they have the following claim $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n}\sqrt\pi.$$ Where $n\in \Bbb N$. I do not see how they got the second.

Comment: I think if you use integration by parts you will get the result.

Answer (score 1):

We [integrate by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts), but "in reverse".  Set $u=e^{-x^2}, dv=x^{2n}dx$, and calculate $du=-2xe^{-x^2}dx, v=\frac{1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$.  Combining, we get $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2}dx= e^{-x^2}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}|_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{-2}{2n+1}x^{2n+2}e^{-x^2}dx$.  However $ e^{-x^2}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}|_{-\infty}^\infty=0$, so in fact $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{2}{2n+1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n+2}e^{-x^2}dx$.  Multiply both sides by $\frac{2n+2}{2}$ to get $$\frac{2n+2}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n}e^{-x^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^{2n+2}e^{-x^2}dx$$

Since this holds for all $n$, we apply it recursively to find the claim.